# How to make a txt file with text from other txt files on a grid-like style?

Tags: c#

So, let's say I have 4 .txt files that look something like this:

```
X X
X X

Y Y
Y Y

A A
A A

B B
B B
```

How could I make a new txt file that contains a random mix of those 4 structures, to make something like this for example:

```
X X A A Y Y
X X A A Y Y
Y Y B B X X
Y Y B B X X
A A Y Y B B
A A Y Y B B
```

So in this case a 3x3 grid.

Comment: I suspect some *code* would be involved.

Comment: Obviously, that's why I tagged it as c# :)

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a free code-writing service. The C# tag means “the code I am including is C#” and you haven't included any code.

Comment: Okay I wasn't asking for the code either, what I was asking is how would you mix the different grids into a bigger one. I don't care about the specific code, just the reasoning behind it. If you don't want to help that's fine, no need to post if you'll just complain though.

Comment: @user1913644 I suggest you read [ask] before you accuse **Dour** of complaining.  He was actually trying to help you.  SO is not like say the MSDN Social forums.  Here's a downvote and close vote for your impertinence

Comment: Your question is nothing more than a set of requirements and suspiciously looks like  homework

Answer (score 0):

I would first convert the separate files to arrays.  Then, assign each array a pseudo-random value.  Once that has been done, concatenate them together into a larger array based on the value assigned to them.

Mock Code:

```
    var listOfFiles = new List<List<String>();

    foreach (file in files)
        listOfFiles.Insert([Random Number], file.ToList())

    listOfFiles.To2DArray(3,3);
```

Where To2DArray() is

```
public static T[,] To2dArray<T>(this List<List<T>> list)
    {
        if (list.Count == 0 || list[0].Count == 0)
            throw new ArgumentException("The list must have non-zero dimensions.");

        var result = new T[list.Count, list[0].Count];
        for (int rows = 0; rows < list.Count; rows++)
        {
            for (int cols = 0; cols < list[rows].Count; cols++)
            {
                if (list[rows].Count != list[0].Count)
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("The list cannot contain elements (lists) of different sizes.");

                result[rows, cols] = list[rows][cols];
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Don't feed the pigeons.  _[Stance on answering “bad” questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281793/stance-on-answering-bad-questions)_ and _[Should one advise on off-topic questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276572/should-one-advise-on-off-topic-questions)_

Comment: @MickyD Fair enough.  Should I delete the answer I gave, or leave it?

Comment: No tis no harm.  Was just letting you know

Comment: I doubt the OP could understand the answer let alone explain it to their instructor we should not give answers in my opinion to individuals that just post requirements or homework assignments without showing that they have at least tried something at the very least..